# Connect to db2 (pdo_odbc) using php (xampp) on windows machine

Tags: pdo, db2, odbc, php

I am trying to connect to db2 with php (xampp) on a windows machine, but it is throwing this error:

> SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

My function is as the following:

```
 function dbConnect($host, $database, $username, $password)
    {
        try 
        {
            $con = new PDO("odbc:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   

            return true;            
        } 
        catch(PDOException $e) 
        {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Notice my php_info is as the following:

[image]

By the way, I haven't downloaded/installed any driver. My assumption, by enabling (extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll) in php.ini, it should be accessible.

Comment: Which part of the error message causes any trouble to you? And instead of the code, it would be better you would add the PDO `$dsn` string verbatim to your question so it becomes more clear what is done *in concrete*, the code alone does not tell the whole story.

Comment: think i am missing something here. didn't know i have to include a dsn.

Comment: any help on how to define the dsn?

Comment: The first parameter of PDO's consructor is named `$dsn`. So actually you knew if that was your code. More information on that one is in the PHP manual on PDO and also in PDO driver specific sections.

Comment: i have always been working with mysql (using the normal mysqli functions). I am new to using db2 and trying to learn pdo to have the flexibility to connect to different dbs with php. If any help can be provided or any baby steps instructions on how to do the above, i would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

In windows, you won't need to download any extra drivers as stated in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php).

Here is the relevant portion from the manual:

> On Windows, PDO_ODBC is built into the PHP core by default. It is linked against the Windows ODBC Driver Manager so that PHP can connect to any database cataloged as a System DSN, and is the recommended driver for connecting to Microsoft SQL Server databases.

So, you would need to define a System DSN to your DB2 (this setup might require ODBC driver for DB2 if you don't already have it) and instantiate PDO as follows:

```
// Replace SYSTEM_DSN_NAME with appropriate name you setup
$con = new PDO("odbc:SYSTEM_DSN_NAME", $username, $password);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. any idea or useful link on how can i define a dsn? never came across that before.

Comment: i have tried doing this instead: <$con = new PDO("odbc:driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$database", $username, $password);> but get the  error: <SQLSTATE[01S00] SQLDriverConnect: -99999 [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0004W Invalid connection string attribute. SQLSTATE=01S00> where i have obtained <IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER> from the odbcinst.ini file. Any idea?

Comment: @NaderKhan, if you've verified your DSN setup on Windows, please post your latest code that you've tried "as is" in your question.